# 1-of-K coding in Octave

Tags: math, for-loop, matrix, octave

I'm trying to get a binary one-of-K coding of a integer vector in Octave. I've got a vector `y`, say

```
y = [1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 1 ; 3]
```

and I want a matrix

```
Y = [1 0 0
     0 1 0
     0 0 1
     1 0 0
     0 0 1]
```

I can construct the one-of-K matrix by hand with

```
Y = [];
Y = [Y y == 1];
Y = [Y y == 2];
Y = [Y y == 3];
```

But when I try to construct it with a `for` loop,

```
Y = [];
for i = unique(y),
    Y = [Y y == i];
endfor
```

something goes wrong:

```
error: mx_el_eq: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 5x1, op2 is 3x1)
```

I don't even understand the error message. Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found it. I wish the tutorial had told me this.

```
Y = [];
for i = unique(y)',
%                ^
%  -------------/
    Y = [Y y == i];
end
```

Apparently, `for` loops through the *columns* of a vector from left to right and `unique` returns a *column vector*, so the "nonconformant arguments" are `y` (5×1) and `unique(y)` (3×1).

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a way to do this without a loop:

```
Y = unique(y)(:,ones(1,size(y,1)))' == y(:,ones(size(unique(y),1),1))
```

Comment: Poor old Octave, forcing us to trade excessive memory use for performance, in absence of a jit.